# Cisco 7604 + RSP720 3CXL + WS-X6704-10GE QOS marking problem

Tags: cisco, qos, cisco-ios-15, cisco-7600

Cisco 7604 + RSP720 3CXL + WS-X6704-10GE, need to understand how much traffic from the client comes to external resources, and how much goes to internal network resources.

Mark incoming traffic to external resources:

```
    interface TenGigabitEthernet3/4.AAA
 description -= WORLD =-
 encapsulation dot1Q AAA
 ip address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
 service-policy input WORLD-IN-MARKING
 service-policy output WORLD-OUT-SHAPING
end

#sh policy-map WORLD-IN-MARKING
  Policy Map WORLD-IN-MARKING
    Class class-default
      set dscp cs1
```

check that passes through the policy-map:

```
#sh policy-map interface Te3/4.AAA input
 TenGigabitEthernet3/4.AAA

  Service-policy input: WORLD-IN-MARKING

    class-map: class-default (match-any)
      Match: any
      set dscp 8:
      Earl in slot 1 :
        164559208445 bytes
        5 minute offered rate 788760744 bps
        aggregate-forwarded 164559208445 bytes
```

bps identical with graphics loading interface.

Client Interface:

```
interface TenGigabitEthernet3/4.BBB
 description -= CLIENT =-
 encapsulation dot1Q BBB
 ip address YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY 
 service-policy output CLIENT-W-IN
end

#sh policy-map CLIENT-W-IN
  Policy Map CLIENT-W-IN
    Class WORLD-IN
     police cir 1000000000 bc 31250000
       conform-action transmit
       exceed-action drop
```

check that passes through the policy-map:

```
#sh policy-map interface TenGigabitEthernet3/4.BBB
 TenGigabitEthernet3/4.BBB

  Service-policy output: CLIENT-W-IN

    class-map: WORLD-IN (match-all)
      Match:  dscp cs1 (8)
      police :
        1000000000 bps 31250000 limit 31250000 extended limit
      Earl in slot 1 :
        411124 bytes
        5 minute offered rate 2568 bps
        aggregate-forwarded 411124 bytes action: transmit
        exceeded 0 bytes action: drop
        aggregate-forward 2216 bps exceed 0 bps

    Class-map: class-default (match-any)
      0 packets, 0 bytes
      5 minute offered rate 0000 bps, drop rate 0000 bps
      Match: any
```

bps shows the value that is much smaller than in the graphs loading interface.

A similar scheme works fine on the Cisco ASR1001.

Tried to mark dscp af11, then set dscp cs1 - no changes.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above-described behavior is by design for the Cisco 76XX platform: See the [Configuration guide for QOS on Cisco 7600's](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/7600/ios/12.2SR/configuration/guide/qos.html.).

Solved the problem of marking traffic on another router before it is sent to this router.

Comment: What do you mean with "by design"?
Why are CLIENT-W-IN counters so low?

Comment: "by design" and "CLIENT-W-IN counters so low" - see the http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/7600/ios/12.2SR/configuration/guide/qos.html. 
Now everything is working well, the CLIENT-W-IN counters were up significantly.